# Android - найти координаты нажатия при долгом тапе

Tags: listener, android, java

Здравствуйте! Есть довольно большой лэйаут, и мне нужно реализовать следующее:

1. Пользователь задерживает палец на случайной точке на лэйауте
2. На этом месте появляется некий View

С появлением View на экране у меня никаких проблем не возникло, однако я не могу отловить координаты долгого нажатия. Я пробовал найти координаты через TouchListener...

```
    final int action = me.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) { //вот тут мы как бы отсеиваем только долгие нажатия
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                int x = (int)me.getX();
                int y = (int)me.getY();
                utils.toast(x + " " + y, true);
                break;
    }
```

...но этот код реагирует просто на нажатие, а не на долгий тап. Как мне заставить код реагировать только на зажатие пальца на лэйауте? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

на мой взгляд самый простой способ это от наследоваться от лайоута и переопределить  `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` в котором просто записывать координаты а дальше вызывать метод родителя, а метод родителя сам вызовет longClick() когда надо. В  longClick() соответственно читать координаты...